# Symfony 4 error where cache:clear or composer update

Tags: caching, symfony4

When I ran `composer update` OR `bin/console cache:clear` it had issue bellow:

> Executing script cache:clear [KO]

> Script cache:clear returned with error code 1

> In ArrayNode.php line 331:

> Unrecognized options "dir_name, namespace" under
> "doctrine_migrations". Ava   !!    ilable options are
> "all_or_nothing", "check_database_platform", "connection   !!    ",
> "custom_template", "em", "factories", "migrations",
> "migrations_paths",    !!    "organize_migrations", "services",
> "storage".

> Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem by changing:
I edited doctrine-migrations.yaml:

Befor:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
```

After:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
```

reference:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.1.x/UPGRADE.md